# What to do with a question that isn't really likely to help anyone apart from the person who asked

Tags: discussion, flags

I often browse Android questions and come across more and more questions about `ListView`, `ViewPager`, `Fragments`, etc ...
It seems to me that a vast majority of these questions aren't useful because:

- OP lack programming knowledge and are asking questions whose problems are caused by programming errors and has less to do with its tags, title, etc ...
- As a consequence, there's a lot of questions where posters want to reuse code but cannot really understand it, and then, post a lot of code which is really painful to read, wanting users to solve their problem because they don't want to pay enough time to learn solving them themselves (and then tomorrow they ask another question for the same lack of knowledge).
- As another consequence, the question in the end isn't likely to help anyone else because it is so specific. Because the question spoils the tag. Because if someone really come across the same problem, it's tagging and title make it unlikely that it will appear as a response to the problem.

(And likely other reasons ...)

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158715/listview-with-baseadapter-android) an example (maybe not the best).

What to do about this ? Should I downvote (I expect it being no because OP often are newcomers in this situation) ? As for flagging, I didn't found a reason that was what I described.

Comment: Downvoting newcomers is fine. Base your votes on the content, not the person.

Comment: If you he is a newcomer, you still downvote, but care to elaborate the why in a comment (possibly include some links to the help pages or even meta). I sometimes even go so far to point out the solution in a comment and then hit the `close` button.

Comment: @Bergi: thanks for teaching newcomers they'll get answers to their questions that don't belong here! We appreciate your dedication to declining site quality!

Comment: @Wooble: It's not a sufficient *answer*, otherwise I would have posted it as an answer. I'm just hinting at the problem, and might link to a solution similar to what they need - it all needs to fit in a comment. The point is to tell them that there's something wrong with their *question* (and what it is and how to improve), but to show them that the community is still trying to be helpful. Of course, it also depends on the attitude of the question *how* helpful I am.